# Why django trying to create migration table when my purpose is just to read existing oracle database

Tags: python, django, cx-oracle

My purpose is to connect to oracle database and run query in order to populate those results on a web page. But when I try to run python manage.py migrate I am getting below error. Even when I use option --fake-initial or --fake same error. I dont want to create any table. I just made changes in settings.py file to connect to oracle database instead of sqlite.

```
    Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 506, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 312, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 506, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (ORA-01031: insufficient privileges)
```

app/models.py

```
from django.db import connection

# Create your models here.

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE")
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

Comment: just fake migrate.
django needs the migration in case you ever wanted to change the data base structure lateron

Comment: @gelonida I tried python manage.py migrate --fake-initial, but still getting same error. Other option --fake getting same error.

Comment: In normally django expects you, that you create the migrations table in your oracle data base, so that django can keep track about the migration status.

Do I understand you, that you do not want to create this migration table in oracle?

I don't know this by heart, but look for an option, that disables the entire migration mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django needs a read/write database as its `default` database to track migrations in a table called `django_migrations`. Change your settings to set up a SQLite (or other) database as your `default` database, then create a second entry called `my_oracle` for your read-only Oracle database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    },
    'my_oracle': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Then you can:

```py
from django.db import connections

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connections["my_oracle"].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE")
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        return row
```

Good luck!